# Having Trouble Understanding Feynman Diagrams

Tags: quantum-mechanics, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

So recently I have became interested in quantum physics. However when I read up on quantum physics Feynman diagrams appear everywhere, and I do not understand them!

Here is a Feynman diagram that is annoying me:
[image]

So, How do I know if that electron and anti-neutrino were there all along, or one created the other?

I also apologize for my immense niaveness.

Comment: Hi Stephen, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! These are not bad questions, but we prefer that you ask one question per post. Could you edit your question to focus it on one specific thing? You can then make separate posts to ask other questions.

Comment: I have changed the question to ask for a general explanation of Feynman diagrams. Is it formatted correctly now?

Comment: Asking for an explanation of Feynman diagrams is still far *too broad*, as a proper explanation involves an entire course on quantum field theory.

Comment: @ACuriousMind is right, but it's getting better. What exactly confuses you about Feynman diagrams? You say you know what the lines represent, so you have a basic understanding; what is it exactly that you _don't_ understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time is going up, and if you keep that in mind I think you can sort out most of your questions. This is a diagram of $\beta$ decay, where a neutron becomes a proton and in the process emits an electron and anti-neutrino. The decay is mediated by the weak force so the $W^-$ boson appears.

So let's break down how I went about reading that. We start at the bottom, where there are the three quarks that make up a neutron. Since this is the only particle in diagram, it's the only relevant particle at the beginning, so when you ask:

> Is the neutron decaying because of a particle or for no explainable reason

There's no other particle colliding with it. Usually when we say "decay" we mean something that happens spontaneously. In particular, this process is very common in un- or less-stable nuclei. Anyway, then we keep scanning up and we get to the first vertex. A vertex (where two lines meet) is always an interaction of some kind. Here we see the down quark in the neutron emits a $W^-$ boson. Next, that $W^-$ boson has another vertex where it decays into the antineutrino and electron. When we get to the top of the diagram (the end of the process) we see that there is now a proton (the quark has changed), an electron, and an anti-neutrino. The $W^-$ does not make it out, which is why we call it "virtual."

> is the virtual w- boson actually emitting a antimatter neutrino and an electron or is is it just showing the interference of them (ex. iron moving by a magnet)

By this I believe you're asking whether an electron/antineutrino that just happens to be nearby is interacting. The answer is no: all relevant particles that go into the interaction have to appear at the beginning of the diagram. This also applies to:

> Is the electron and neutrino being created right there or is the neutrino being transformed into an electron (if so how do you know that when reading it)

Notice that their lines start at the $W^-$ vertex, indicating that they did not exist before this--you can imagine that line as tracing out the electron's life in space-time. If the neutrino or electron were present before the process began (and therefore just interacting with the $W^-$ emitted by the neutron) they'd be present at the bottom of the diagram.

> If times going up it looks like both an antimatter neutrino and an electron are being created (If so or not so how can you tell what's happening)

Yes. It's interesting to consider the reaction sort of paradigm, which you would see if you were reading nuclear physics books rather than QFT stuff. There we might write:
$$
n \to p + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e
$$
You can extract this from a Feynman diagram just by looking at the very bottom and very top of the diagram. Everything that occurs within is is internal dynamics: it tells you *how* things happened, but *what* happened is just the input-output of the diagram, and is what we would usually think of actually observing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot.

1) I'm not crazy about the term emitting.   The W- boson turns into an Electron and anti Neutrino.   Emitting suggests it's still there after the fact.  It becomes the Electron and Anti Neutrino.

(Source):  http://pfnicholls.com/physics/particles4.html

2) Both the electron and anti Neutrino are created at the same time.  You can't transform a Neutrino into an Electron because the charge isn't consistent.

3) Yes, both are created at the same time.

4) Generally speaking, the Neutron decays because it's a higher energy state that wants to get to a lower energy state - it's similar to why hot objects cool down (Kinda-sorta) or why anything with a half life decays.   We might think of Neutrons as stable cause most atoms are stable, but Neutrons are only stable when bound to protons, not on their own.   The half life of a loose Neutron is about 10 minutes.